# Proving that $g(x)=x|x|$ is differentiable at $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, derivatives, definition

> Define $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=x|x|$. Prove that $g$ is differentiable at $0$.

Am I still able to use the precise definition of the limit if the function is a composition of two functions? or do I have to use the product rule?

Comment: You can't use the product rule for differentiability at $0$, because $|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: $g(x)$ is not a composition it is a product. You might want to graph the function first to get a 'feel for it'.

Comment: Gee, learn something new everyday! - The hackers version of $f(x) = x^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are able to use the definition:$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}x=\lim_{x\to0}\lvert x\rvert=0.$$